# list websites requiring that my browser is signed into Gmail

Tags: openid

Is there a way to list which websites authenticate by requiring that my browser sign into Gmail? It would probably be a Gmail or Google Account feature if it exists. I am not asking to list which websites support third-party (Gmail) authentication but rather which websites I have currently set up to rely upon my Gmail authentication.

For example, I joined medium.com and the identifier is supposed to be an email address. I provided a gmail.com address and I was not required to provide a new password to medium.com. It so happened that I was already signed into Gmail in a different browser tab. This annoyed me because some other websites make this behavior optional.  I don't know what would happen if I were not already signed in to Gmail but I suspect I would be prompted to sign into Gmail, making it obvious that providing a new password to medium.com is not supported.

Some websites make this third-party reliance optional even if your identifier is a gmail.com address. I recall using a website (I don't remember which) that even allows the reliance on Gmail to be "forgotten" so that you must use/supply a new password.

Comment: The website doesn't require you to be logged into GMail, it requires that you have a *cookie* from GMail in your browser. As long as that cookie remains, you should be able to authenticate using your GMail account.

Answer (score -1):

You mean this?

"Manage your Google Account" > "Security" > "Third party apps with account access"

[image: Apps using my Google account as SSO]

---

Also, your medium.com example is surprising; you should at have to click through a prompt authorizing Google to release your personal info (your name, email address, etc) to medium.com. If any random website you're on can just ask Google who you are without you having to consent, then the whole concept of internet privacy is shot to hell, so I find that highly suspicious.

If your concern is just that medium.com does not have their own user account system and forces you to give them your Google account; well, then don't use medium.com -- this is the general advice "if you don't like the terms of service, then don't use the service".